# Hindi character support in MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have spatial MS SQL 2012 and i need to store hindi characters in a column. 
I tried using nvarchar datatype but I'm getting only "`Question marks(????)`".

Is it possible to store non-english characters?